# Ошибка при компиляции java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation

Tags: scala

При запуске проекта на *Scala* компилятор дает ошибку

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: can't seal
>   package scala: already loaded

на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093176/java-lang-securityexception-sealing-violation) нашел такое решение: там предлагают поменять в джарнике `sealed` на `false`, но у меня и так и `false`.

```
Name: oracle/sql/converter/
Sealed: false

Name: oracle/sql/
Sealed: false
```

Может кто-то знает ответ на этот вопрос?

Comment: Можно полный stack trace?